# Is this a condition to be order isomorphic to a subset of the integers?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

Let $S$ be a totally ordered set such that any nonempty subset of $S$ bounded above has a greatest element and any nonempty subset of $S$ bounded below has a least element.  Is $S$ order isomorphic to a subset of the integers?

Comment: @JensRenders: No, an empty subset _does not_ contain a least element (or a greatest one).

Comment: @EricWofsey Yes thank you.  I've updated the question to match this.

Comment: @JensRenders: It would be _true_ but uninterestingly so, because the only $S$ that satisfies the assumption is then $S=\varnothing$. With Eric Wofsey's correction there is actually something to prove.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Assume without loss of generality that $S$ has a least element. (Otherwise pick an element and handle the part of $S$ above and below the chosen element separately -- for those below mutatis mutandis with the order swapped).

Now we can keep assigning the "smallest element of $S$ not yet used" to integers starting with $0$ and counting upwards. (After the first step, the set of integers not yet used is always bounded below by the original least element).

This can *either* end when we've used up all of the elements, *or* when we've assigned elements to all the natural numbers. But in the latter case, the set of elements that we *have* assigned yet cannot be upwards bounded in $S$ -- because then they would have a largest element, which they haven't -- so also in that case there cannot be any elements left.

Answer (score 0):

Pick any element $a\in S$, and consider $T=\{x\in S:a\leq x\}$ and $U=S\setminus T$.

Every subset of $T$ has least element, so $T$ is well ordered, and thus order isomorphic to some ordinal number. Now for every $\alpha > \omega$, take $\omega \subset \alpha$ to be subset bounded above with no greatest element. This imply, that $T$ is order isomorphic to some subset of $\mathbb{N}$. Dual argumentation shows that $U$ is order isomorphic to subset of $\mathbb{Z}\setminus\mathbb{N}$.